# Are all TIE pilots also Imperial Officers

Tags: star-wars

The code cylinders used by Imperial Officers typically resemble R. A. Stephen 0-5 rad direct-reading dosimeters with a spring brass clip and anodized blue top. The code cylinders used by rebel pilots are the rod style with multiple turned features at the top and a thin cylindrical stem.

Every military I am familiar with has pilots considered officers. Yes, some may be warrant officers, but TIE pilots should still be considered officers serving the Empire nonetheless. All of the Imperial Officers I am familiar with have used the same Imperial-issue code cylinders. Numerous rebel pilots are seen using their own rebel style of code cylinders.

Is there any evidence of TIE pilots using the rebel pilot style code cylinder? Is there any evidence that TIE pilots are not officers and should therefore not use Imperial Officer-style code cylinders?

Edit:

Admiral Motti was seen with two rebel-style and one different direct-reading dosimeter-style code cylinder in:

http://starwarsblog.starwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/motti.jpg

I am just wondering if there is a canon reason why all pilots would be prohibited from using a standard military device common to almost all of the officers in the Imperial Navy.

Comment: The US Army has non-commisioned officers as pilots (most people mean _commissioned_ officer [ie, lieutenant or higher] when the say officer). The RAF also had sergeant pilots in WWII

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. I have never met a pilot who is an NCO, but I have met numerous warrant officer or commissioned officer pilots. As one of about 1,000 pilots in this section of the galaxy with a type rating in the ANH-variant TIE fighter I'm just looking for a canon reason why my originally-approved demilitarized equipment (including the dosimeter-style code cylinder) is now considered not approvable. The answer might likely be above my pay grade.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't directly answer your question about code cylinders, but does address whether TIE pilots are officers (they are).

This would imply that they have earned access to code cylinders, but may not need them as part of their pilot duties.

---

The [*Wookieepedia page on Flight School*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Flight_school) says:

> Flight school was the name of the Imperial Navy's system for training TIE pilots. It was not a part of the Imperial Academy, however. Instead, *the Navy's best junior **officers*** would transfer to flight school after they left the Academy system.

It claims *The Imperial Sourcebook* as a reference, but I don't own it so I can't verify.

---

Other observations about officers and code cylinders:

- Petty Officers don't wear them. Their "not quite officer" rank may not deserve them. (examples are Petty Officer Thanisson and Chief Petty Officer Unamo, on p. 43 of *The Force Awakens Visual Dictionary*)
- Warrant Officers apparently don't wear them. (example is Suday Bascus, on p. 30 of *The Last Jedi Visual Dictionary*)
- General Hux doesn't wear them. But as General, he probably doesn't need them -
  he could just command another officer to use theirs.